# Почему пустая структура весит 1 байт?

Tags: c++, c, структуры

```c
struct t1 {};

int s0 = sizeof(t1); // почему 1, а не 0?
```

Comment: Документация говорит "The sizeof operator never yields 0, even for an empty class."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632075/8343843

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Потому что два указателя на различные объекты обязаны быть различными.

Если даже что-то может занимать 0 байт, то ему всё равно нужен уникальный адрес, а минимальным адресуемым пространством является байт. Вот и получается, что пустая структура занимает этот байт, хотя никак его не использует.

Comment: Интересно, а выравнивание в памяти к этому тоже применимо, и т.о. пустой объект займет еще больше?

Comment: @Kromster, полагаю, выравнивание будет работать так же, как с char. Есть причины делать иначе? Почему должен занять больше, я не понял. На char же не надо больше. Впрочем, если положить в другую структуру перед int'ом, то у меня сомнения, что получится, а именно, не может ли он соптимизировать до выкидывания поля вообще.

Comment: Да тут просто нечего выравнивать, если только не объявить это явно:  struct alignas(4) t1 {
};

Comment: А нет, все ок, чары не выравниваются )

Comment: @Qwertiy Может, если захочет :) - на то оптимизация пустого базового класса...

Comment: @Harry, а полей она тоже касается?

Comment: @Kromster, char'ы выравниваются по 1 байту, short'ы по 2 и так далее. Точнее говоря, они выравниваются по своему размеру, если он меньше битности программы.

Comment: @Qwertiy Упс. Я почему-то, читая ваше, перед глазами видел наследование. Наверное, нет - потому как тогда поля могут иметь одинаковые адреса.

Comment: По стандарту си, вообще запрещено иметь пустые структуры.  Как и пустые юниты трансляции.

Comment: @Harry, но ведь поля разных типов. По strict aliasing мы не можем сравнивать поле одного типа с полем другого типа (правда, мы можем оба привести к char и сравнить), так что вполне возможно, что это допустимо. Или нет?

Comment: @mik.ov, но по C++ разрешено.

Comment: @Harry, https://ideone.com/fztDA4 - вот, 8 получилось, а не 4.

Comment: Не до конца понятна связь между "два указателя на различные объекты обязаны быть различными" и "пустая структура весит 1 байт", вроде ничего не мешает указателям быть разными даже при нулевом размере объекта.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, две ситуации. 1. Если структура весит 0 байт и я делаю массив из 2 таких структур, то сколько весит массив? Если 0 байт, то у обоих его элементов один адрес. 2. Если структура занимает 0 байт, то что мешает использовать адрес, по которому она находится, для других данных? Но тогда у структуры и тех данных одинаковый адрес, что запрещено. А если использовать нельзя, то получается, что структура не даёт использовать тот байт, чей адрес ей достался. А это как раз означает, что она занимает 1 байт. Ну и выравнивания в других структурах могут сделать этот байт несколько жирнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy (_гипотетически_) массив из двух пустых структур может весить 0 байт, при этом элементы будут иметь разные указатели, и разница между ними (ptrdiff_t) будет составлять единицу. Использовать повторно адрес, занимаемый таким массивом под другие данные не получится, т.к. к примеру оператор new не вернет указатель на этот массив.

Comment: Т.е. понятно, что есть причина, почему в плюсах минимальный размер данных равен единице, но кажется дело не в указателях.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113937/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladimir-gamalyan).

Comment: *"два указателя на различные объекты обязаны быть различными"* На различные объекты одного типа. </занудство>

Answer (score 5):

В С++ один байт (точнее `sizeof(char)`), в Си (в тех расширениях языка, где резрешены пустые структуры) ноль.

По крайней мере GNU компилятор `gcc/g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` для всех стандартов **языка Си** (*-std= c90,gnu90,c99,gnu99,c11,gnu11*) разрешает использовать пустую структуру и говорит, что ее **размер** (`sizeof(...)`)  **равен нулю**.

Для пустой структуры во всех стандартах **C++** (*-std= c+98,gnu++98,c++11,gnu++11,c++14,gnu++14,c++1z,gnu++1z*) этот же компилятор также разрешет испольковать пустые структуры, но **размер** такого объекта **равен 1.**

P.S.
на мой взгляд, такое расхождение это форменное безобразие (для Си), поскольку печатая адреса последовательно определенных переменных с типом такой пустой структуры, вы можете заметить, что реально в памяти под каждую из них отводится 1 байт.

P.P.S
Clang тоже разрешает пустые структуры, для Си **размер 0.**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113945/discussion-on-answer-by-avp-----1-).

Comment: Нет одного байта в си: https://ideone.com/9ppJMz.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а разве я писал, что выделение 1 байта происходит для элементов структуры? Адрес у них очевидно есть, это адрес следующего члена структуры. Память выделяется, если это переменная "верхнего уровня", программа видит это имя без квалификации. / Вообще с памятью еще интересней. Каждой переменной в стеке дается свой адрес, а всем пустым статическим  (даже разного типа и не важно static/extern) одинаковый. Как-то так.